# Node.js runtime wrapper

Tags: node.js

Are there any node.js runtime wrappers generators similar to [gradle wrapper](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html) that allows to build node.js application without installing the node runtime globally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there are many projects that aim to make bundling Node.js with your apps easy:

- [node-bundler](https://github.com/desertnet/node-bundler)
- [Nexe](https://github.com/nexe/nexe) (doesn't support dynamic `require` statements)
- [EncloseJS](http://enclosejs.com/buy) (paid)

If you're starting a GUI project from scratch, then [Electron](http://electron.atom.io/) or [NW.js](https://nwjs.io/) allow you to bundle up a browser with your app to allow using JS, HTML and CSS.

There are also some experimental JavaScript-to-uninterpreted compilers in the work:
[ts2c](https://github.com/andrei-markeev/ts2c) converts TypeScript to C which can then be compiled with gcc or clang, and there's an unreleased project called [Nectar](http://blog.seraum.com/nectar-a-native-cross-platform-javascript-ecmascript-compiler-inspired-by-crystal-lang-and-nim-lang) that aims to compile JS to machine code directly.